# I cannot turn ON/OFF flash Barcode Detection in Google Play services?

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode, google-vision, camera-flash

I tried to turn on and turn off the flash when I use the camera with Barcode Detection in Google Play services, in several problems they say that the solution is setFashMode method of the class CameraSource but I did not find this method

cameraSource = CameraSource.Builder(mActivity,detector).setRequestedPreviewSize(1024,900)
            .setRequestedFps(50f).setAutoFocusEnabled(true).build()